# Open iframe in a modal when click on Book

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

i have the next iframe from Bokun:

```html
<div id="bokun-w35050_53624920_43ac_48d9_9b42_b6b315d250f4">Loading...</div><script type="text/javascript">
var w35050_53624920_43ac_48d9_9b42_b6b315d250f4;
(function(d, t) {
  var host = 'widgets.bokun.io';
  var frameUrl = 'https://' + host + '/widgets/35050?bookingChannelUUID=7279350f-e510-44e6-b5fc-d7515f01dfff&amp;activityId=68154&amp;lang=en&amp;ccy=USD&amp;hash=w35050_53624920_43ac_48d9_9b42_b6b315d250f4';
  var s = d.createElement(t), options = {'host': host, 'frameUrl': frameUrl, 'widgetHash':'w35050_53624920_43ac_48d9_9b42_b6b315d250f4', 'autoResize':true,'height':'','width':'100%', 'minHeight': 0,'async':true, 'ssl':true, 'affiliateTrackingCode': '', 'transientSession': true, 'cookieLifetime': 43200 };
  s.src = 'https://' + host + '/assets/javascripts/widgets/embedder.js';
  s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
    try { 
      w35050_53624920_43ac_48d9_9b42_b6b315d250f4 = new BokunWidgetEmbedder(); w35050_53624920_43ac_48d9_9b42_b6b315d250f4.initialize(options); w35050_53624920_43ac_48d9_9b42_b6b315d250f4.display();
    } catch (e) {}
  };
  var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');
</script>
```

what i need is it Open checkout in a new modal when clicked on Book

Comment: can you explain better please I'm a noob at  javaScript

Comment: So no. To make their button do that, a deep analysis of the code is needed. It would be easier to ask a developer to look at https://bokun.github.io/api-docs/ to see if their code can be made to do this